# Is using setUp/tearDown beneficial for unmodified objects in a unit test?

Tags: ios

Is using setUp/tearDown beneficial for unmodified objects in a unit test?

I know if the object in question needs to be modified and keep track of its state in any way it would obviously be beneficial to use the setUp/tearDown methods, but what about an object that isn't modified?

I should clarify that `myObj` in the below example is an object under test.

```
class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    var myObj: MyObj?

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        myObj = MyObj()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        myObj = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }

    ...
}
```

vs.

```
class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    let myObj = MyObj()

    ...
}
```

**EDIT**: What sparked this question for me was watching Jon Reid's recent Quality Coding video about TDD: https://youtu.be/4-KrgRH_Yb0?t=7m57s. Notice how he refactors out the `sut` into `setUp` and `tearDown`. I was wondering why he didn't just initialize it when he declared it as an instance variable.

Comment: I feel like this question is dancing around the edges of something deeper. The case you describe above is pretty obvious--a static string used in multiple subclass tests is probably best declared as a class property on the base class. Is there some more subtle question you're trying to answer?

Comment: @Palpatim see my edit for why I'm asking.

Comment: To be programmatic, let's say that objects, that are not subject of the tests can be class level objects as usual and objects, that are subjects of tests, should be initialized and teared down in a controlled environment like `setup` and `teardown`. Would such a rule help you?

Comment: I didn't make this clear, but my question is referencing objects that are subject to test. I'm wondering _why_ I should create them in `setUp` and `tearDown` as opposed to initializing in declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my question is referencing objects that are subject to test. I'm wondering why I should create them in `setUp` and `tearDown` as opposed to initializing in declaration

The problem is that in your question the example object referenced is a String. There would be *no* reason not to initialize a string in a declaration.

However, suppose this is an actual object, such as MyCoolViewController. Now we're talking about something that bears a good deal of state, which may be exactly what we are here to exercise. Clearly we'd like to start with a clean slate each time we run this test (or this suite of tests). Thus it makes a great deal of sense to re-initialize in `setUp`. And since this thing may be somewhat heavyweight, it makes sense to destroy it `tearDown` as well.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I shouldn't have made that object a String as it kind of undermined the purpose of the question. I've updated the question.